# Is there any programming project that implements one QKD protocol or demonstrates it?

Tags: cryptography, qkd

There are lots of [quantum key distribution (QKD) protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum_key_distribution_protocols). e.g.

- BB84
- E91 protocol
- BBM92 protocol
- B92 protocol
- MSZ96
- Six-state protocol
- DPS protocol
- Decoy state protocol
- SARG04
- COW protocol
- Three-stage quantum cryptography protocol
- KMB09 protocol
- HDQKD
- T12 protocol

It seems that BB84 and SARG04 are the most famous protocols.

My question is:
Is there any programming project that **implements** one QKD protocol or **demonstrates** one QKD protocol? **which one is the most famous/practical?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are such projects! The codes are on GitHub, alongside an explanation of the protocols, which makes understanding the protocols like a walk in the park!
Here's the link: https://github.com/topics/quantum-key-distribution?o=desc&s=updated